# how can I make specific routes accessible only for specific users in flask?

Tags: flask

I'm using flask and mongodb, I have a user table where it has a boolean attribute **is_admin** and I want to make specefic views and routes accessible only for admin users, I have read about Flask-admin and Flask-Principal but they seemed complicated to me since I am very beginner and its just a school project, is there a way to achieve that without using Flask-Principle?.
for example I want only admin to access this route

```
@users.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add():
    form = UserForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate():
            user = User(username=form.username.data, password= generate_password_hash(form.password.data), vorname=form.vorname.data, nachname=form.nachname.data, geburtsdatum=form.geburtsdatum.data, email=form.email.data, admin=form.admin.data, aktiv=form.aktiv.data)
            user.save()
            flash("user added successfully.", "success")
            return redirect(url_for('.index'))
    return render_template('form.html', users=users, form=form, info=session)
```

Comment: might want to look at flask_login, then use current_user to check that boolean value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this might be what you're looking for:

```py
from flask_login import current_user
# use the suggested pattern to login user then..

@users.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add():
    if not current_user.is_admin:
        abort(403)
    # rest of your route
```

This will return HTTP 403 - Forbidden
as per wikipedia:

> The HTTP 403 is a HTTP status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden. The server understood the request, but will not fulfill it.